# How to load the data from a .sqlite3 file to a Ruby on Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have a production.sqlite3 file which I want to import its data to the current rails project, the database schema is match between the file and my current project. I did copy the content to the development.sqlite3 file but this does not work. The only way I know to insert data to the database is by loading some yml file or use the seed command. Is there any magic command or other ways to let the rails loading the data from .sqlite file? Because from what I disover, the behavior of rails is that it only creates the .sqlite3 file when you do rake db:create &migrate, but it will ignore what ever manual changes happen in that file. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like renaming your .sqlite3 file should work. Make sure you have restarted your server, and that the server is running in the correct environment. If you move both the .sqlite3 files into a completely different folder, and restart the server, an error should occur. If it doesn't, your server didn't properly restart - kill all ruby processes and try again.

In answer to your question about migrating data, I had a similar problem recently, where I had to migrate from sqlite3 to mysql. Best solution I found was [yaml_db](https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db). It seemed to do the job beautifully - add it to the project, then do

```
rake db:data:dump
```

Swap the database configurations (or migrate a new database file, or change your development environment, whatever it is you need to do to make an empty but structured database active), then:

```
rake db:data:load
```